# Word vba, determine range of pages already selected

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know how to select specific pages and how to use Selection.

However, how do you determine which pages have been selected in Word?

Thanks in advance!

Michael

Comment: That depends... how are you selecting these pages and how are you using Selection?  Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and then see "[ask]".  If, after [*doing more research*](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), you have a *specific* problem, you can [edit] your post to share your **[mcve]** as well as sample(s) of your data and some background info. Here's a [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Good Luck!

Comment: Using Selection is very inefficient; it's also generally unnecessary to select anything when using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might start with something like:

```
Sub Demo()
With Selection.Characters
  MsgBox "Your selection spans page(s): " & _
    .First.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & " - " & _
    .Last.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @macropod!  I understand the issue with Selection.  However, but I need to know what user has selected for VBA to do what it needs to do...which will be based upon pages selected.